# Change repeater border colour through code

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater which is visible only by managers where they can accept/reject leave requests made by the users.

The following code while binding my repeater, retrieves if there are any employees on leave working in the same department and on the same date as the one requested by the user.

```
 protected void RptLeaveRequests_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
 {
     otherEmpsLeave = new LeaveLogic().CheckEmployeeLeaveOnDateInSameDep(date, currEmp);
     if (otherEmpsLeave != "")
     {
          //change border of repeater row to another colour and display otherEmpsLeave when manager hovers on repeater row
     }
 }
```

How can I change repeater row border colour (ex add a red border to make it stand out) and display `otherEmpsLeave` on hover?

ASP Repeater Code:

```
<h3>LEAVE REQUESTS</h3>
<asp:Label ID="LblNoRequests" Visible="false" Font-Size="14px" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:HiddenField ID="dataGroups" runat="server" />
<asp:Repeater ID="RptLeaveRequests" runat="server" 
        onitemdatabound="RptLeaveRequests_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <table id="tableItem" runat="server">
    <tr>
    <td style="width:400px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeId" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("EmployeeId") %>' Visible="false" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnEmployeeId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("EmployeeId") %>' />
                <asp:Literal Text="" runat="server" ID="LiteralUser" ></asp:Literal>
    </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
                <td style="width: 100px;">
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnRequestId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("id") %>' />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Date", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 80px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblHours" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Hours") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 50px; font-size:10px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPeriod" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("AMorPM") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 850px; font-size:10px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNote" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Note") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 50px;">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtVerified" runat="server" Visible='<%#!(Boolean)Eval("ReadOnly") %>' >
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Accept</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Reject</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <div style="border-style: dotted; border-color:Black; width:100%; border-width:1px; border-color:#999999"></div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the MSDN example, something like

```
void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {

      // This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.

      // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {

         if (((Evaluation)e.Item.DataItem).Rating == "Good") {
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("RatingLabel")).Text= "<b>***Good***</b>";
         }
      }
   }
```

instead of setting .Text set whatever property(s) you need, such as Background or Tooltip

Comment: this is good but instead of a label I want to set the border of current row

Comment: Add an id to the row, add tag `runat="server"` and find the row instead of label.

Comment: @afzalulh thanks, I will try it out. What about the tooltip, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Add `Title` attribute like `myTr.Attributes.add("Title", "My Tooltip");`